# Unable to use GL tracer on my Android app due to long initalization time

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, opengl-es

I was able to use GL tracer on my Android apps in the past.
The issue I am having now is that my app is doing some CPU processing on init and since GL tracer starts working from the first frame it collects data during the initial processing.
That in turn makes the processing even slower and makes my trace file very big and stuck on the second frame.

I tried disabling all the data collection(there are 3 options) but then the GL tracer complains the application launch timeout has reached and it aborts the tracing.

I tried searching where to change the GL Tracer application launch timeout but couldn't find anything.

I am using eclipse Luna, with an up to date ADT on a Nexus 7 with KitKat(4.4.4).
I saw there is also GL tracing on the KitKat developer options but I am not sure that is what I actually need.

How can I make GL Tracer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered that in DDMS there is the GL tracer icon as well.
So you can run your app and select it at DDMS and then you can click the GL Tracer icon.
This time the package and activity text boxes are greyed out and you can start your GL Tracer data collection while the app is already running.

I never noticed this before, it might be something that was added in Eclipse Luna and you might be able to do this with the GL Tracer perspective as well but now that I do have this option it solves my issue.